# How to compare int input to a list

Tags: python

Write a Python program that will load list A with 15 random numbers (range : 35
– 50). Display list A in ascending order. Then get a number X. Compare X to each
element of A, if list element is less than X, replace that element with X . On
another line, display elements of A after replacing all elements less than X with X.

I got the random list but I don't know how I can compare the X to the list. Please help. So far this is the only code I have.

```py
import random

listA = []
i = 15
for num in range(i):
    num = random.randint(35, 50)
    listA.append(num)
print("Elements of A: ", sorted(listA))
```

A sample run should look like this:

```
Output 1 : Elements of A : 35 35 37 38 39 39 42 43 46 47 47 48 49 50 50
Input X : 37 
New elements of A : 37 37 37 38 39 39 42 43 46 47 47 48 49 50 50
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random

A = list()

for i in range(15):
    A.append(random.randint(35, 50))

A.sort(reverse=False)
print(A)

X = int(input("Write a number to compare with: "))

for i in range(15):
    if X > A[i]:
        A[i] = X

print(A)
```

Comment: I am a beginner in Python.thanks for your guidance @Wolf

Comment: I think your answer is getting okay. I suggest to think about the `reverse` parameter, if not being set to `True`, it's redundant. Also add a bit of text to explain your approach, even if the question reads like a coding task, your answer has not to look like just fulfilling it. To be honest the original question looks to me like fake: how on earth can using random functions be easy and comparing hard?

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this to iterate listA and check if that element is equals than x.

```
x = int(input("Set x: "))
```

```py
for element in listA:
    if element == x:
        pass
```

But, the problem asks **replace that element with X**, so, it is better this:

```
for i in range(len(listA)):
    if listA[i] < x:
        listA[i] = x
```

In this way you'll resolve **if list element is less than X, replace that element with X**.

PS: If x raises an error because it cannot be an integer (example: set x = hi) you could check before int() in this way:

```
import sys

x = input("Set x: ")
if x.isdigit():
    x = int(x)
else:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: *Then get a number X* - I'd read this as: get input. BTW: why do you start with code that is probably not solving the actual task?

Comment: Sample Output 1 :
Elements of A : 35 35 37 38 39 39 42 43 46 47 47 48 49 50 50
Input X : 37
New elements of A : 37 37 37 38 39 39 42 43 46 47 47 48 49 50 50

Comment: hear is the sample output but I don't know how

Comment: @Daniel better add the sample output (and input) to your question

Comment: You change 35s with 37 because 35 is less than 37.

Comment: It's preferred to use the `enumerate` built-in instead of a `range(len(_))` in a for-loop. This allow you to access the index and list item, as well as being clearer in intent.

Answer (score 0):

what if you try this out?

```
import random

listA = []
i = 15
for num in range(i):
    num = random.randint(35, 50)
    listA.append(num)
print("Elements of A (BEFORE): ", sorted(listA))

random_input = int(input("Write a number... > "))

# Here we search for j in listA
for j in listA:
# Then we compare it to the input and exclude the smaller ones
    if j < random_input:
# We create a var which represents the position of the object in the list based on j
        k = listA.index(j)
# And then we replace k place in the list with our random input
        listA[k] = random_input     

print("Elements of A (AFTER): ", sorted(listA))
```

Comment: Thanks men. This means a lot to me haha.

Comment: extremely complicated and inefficient solution, that should not guide any beginner